# Need help understanding a bandwidth restriction on a Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, qos

We have a guest wireless network here and it's bandwidth is limited too 1 Meg per second. I did not configure this and am trying to pick it up.

I've found these lines in the cisco config but i'm not sure how it identifies the network to apply this policy could someone please help me wrap my head around this.

```
class-map Guest_Wireless-class

 match access-list Guest_Wireless_mpc

class-map NetFlow-traffic

!

!


policy-map Guest_Wireless-policy

 class Guest_Wireless-class

  police input 1000000 1500

  police output 1000000 1500
```

Also does this command limit 1 meg per connection or 1 meg total for the guest network?

thanks so much! if you need any more info let me know

Comment: Can you post the contents of the Guest_Wireless_mpc access-list please?

Comment: Also search for lines starting with service-policy as they will tell you which interface the map applies.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question on the policing/limiting :

The input and output are being policed to 1000000 bits per second with a maximum burst of 1500 bytes. The burst value is the max number of bytes in a sustained burst that is allowed before traffic throttled to the specified rate of 100000 bits per second.

This class belongs to a policy-map which can be bound to an interface with a service-policy so these limits would be applied to the physical interface rather than a specific network or subnet.

Details on the parameters for policy & class maps is available [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/asa_84_cli_config/conns_qos.html#wpxref99006).  Also [this](http://slazyk.com/2009/08/bandwidth-policing-throttling-cisco-asa/) blog has a decent post with a  practical example of how to implement bandwidth throttling/policing on an ASA.